# how can i read in a binary file given path-to-file in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, file, ionic-framework

ionic v6.20
angular v14

on iOS and Android i take a picture and am given the path to the image file. i simply want to read in that file and store the contents in a blob. sounds simple, but i've had no luck finding an example of doing just that. NOTE: storing the result in a BLOB is simple, i just need to read the contents of the image!

i've tried various functions that i found in "FileReader()", but they expect a BLOB as the parameter.

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
   console.log(reader.result);
}
reader.readAsText(path-to-image);
```

where path-to-image (a string!) looks like '/tmp/blah/blah/image.jpg'. Perhaps there's something else besides FileReader(), but i have no idea what. can someone help this somewhat novice TypeScript coder?

Comment: Hey... what camera plugin are you using?

Comment: using the capacitor camera api

Comment: Cool, I use the exact one but what do you mean by "read the contents of the image?" Have you checked out all the options returned here => https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/camera#photo
If the problem is creating a blob, I can show you how to create one using the base64string option

Comment: Oh! i was looking at "image.path" and saw "/blah/blah/photo.jpg" and assumed(!) i had to open the file and read it to get the actual image bits. looks like i can use "image.base64String" and have it....right?

Comment: I guess... I'm still not sure what you are trying to do though. 

Image.webPath will contain a path that can be set as an image src. You can access the original file using image.path, which can be passed to the Filesystem API to read the raw data of the image, or pass resultType: CameraResultType.Base64 to getPhoto.